# How can I configure the perl App::Cmd module to complain about incorrect options

Tags: perl, cpan

I'm attempting to use the perl [App::Cmd](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/App-Cmd-0.320/lib/App/Cmd.pm) module and a simple test program works fine.

However, if I run the program with an --option that I haven't configured in the opt_spec
function (of the sub command I'm invoking), it doesn't complain about an invalid option. I would expect it to do so. Instead it just quietly ignores that option.

I can't see anyway of configuring App::Cmd to complain about invalid options.

Is this possible, or is each sub-command expected to do the checking itself?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As per App::Cmd tutorial https://metacpan.org/dist/App-Cmd/view/lib/App/Cmd/Tutorial.pod  Arguments are processed by Getopt::Long::Descriptive (GLD) (check Arguments and Options section https://metacpan.org/dist/App-Cmd/view/lib/App/Cmd/Tutorial.pod#Arguments-and-Options)

For example, jobstatus is a command required job id as parameter

> mycli jobstatus -j 1111  or mycli jobstatus --jobid 1111  # valid command options

```
sub opt_spec {
  # check https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long#Summary-of-Option-Specifications
  return (
    [ "jobid|j=i",  "specify job id" ],
  );
}

sub validate_args {
  my ($self, $opt, $args) = @_;
  # The $opt object will be a dynamically-generated subclass of Getopt::Long::Descriptive::Opts. In brief, each of the options in @opt_spec becomes an accessor method on the object, using the first-given name, with dashes converted to underscores.
  # So object $opt->jobid parameter value is 1111 (jobid 1111 consider as option) and -k consider as argument
  $self->usage_error("Please verify given arguments @$args \n") if @$args;
}
```

> Output

```
> perl mycli jobstatus -j 1111 -k
> Error: Please verify given arguments -k

Usage: mycli <command> [-?h] [long options...]
        -? -h --help  show help

mycli jobstatus [-j] [long options...]
        -j INT --jobid INT  specify job id
```